# Unique representation: $a!\cdot b!\cdot c!=m!\cdot n!\cdot p!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Let $a,b,c\ge 3$ be natural numbers. If $a\le b\le c$ and $m\le n\le p$ the following proposition is true?

$$
a!\cdot b!\cdot c!=m!\cdot n!\cdot p!\to (a,b,c)=(m,n,p)
$$

$$
a!\cdot b!=m!\cdot n!\to (a,b)=(m,n)
$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The part about two is wrong

$$  4! 15! = 7! 13! $$

$$  3! 20! = 5! 19! $$

$$  4! 30! = 6! 29! $$

$$  5! 42! = 7! 41! $$

$$  6! 56! = 8! 55! $$

$$  18! 57! = 22! 54! $$

$$  7! 66! = 14! 62! $$

$$  7! 72! = 9! 71! $$

$$  8! 90! = 10! 89! $$

=========================================

$$ 3! 3! 16! = 4! 4! 15! = 4! 7! 13! = 2^{17} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot  13 $$
$$ 3! 8! 13! = 4! 6! 14!  = 2^{18} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot  13 $$

$$ 3! 4! 20! = 4! 5! 19!  = 2^{18} \cdot 3^8 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11 \cdot  13 $$

Answer (score 2):

$4!4!25! = 5!5!24!$

$5!5!36! = 6!6!35!$

$6!4!35! = 7!5!34!$ ....

$a!b![(a+1)(b+1)]! = (a+1)!(b+1)![(a+1)(b+1)-1]!$

Answer (score 2):

The famous
$$n! \cdot (n!-1)!=(n!)!=(n!)! \cdot 1! $$
is a counterexample for 2, and can be extended to $3$:

$$1!\cdot1!\cdot((n!)!)!=(n!)! ((n!)!-1)!=n! \cdot(n!-1)! \cdot((n!)!-1)!$$

Answer (score 1):

Combine $6!7!=10!$ with @N.S.'s answer

$$6!7!(n!)!=10!n!(n!-1)!$$

- $6!7!24!=4!10!23!$
- $6!7!120!=5!10!119!$
- $6!7!720!=6!10!719!$